# Release does not run. This application failed to start

Tags: qt, dll

My application works when it built in debug mode. But it does not run in release.

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platform plugin "windows".
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

I copied dlls which the application required. I copied also qwindows.dll, qoffscreen.dll and libEGL.dll.

But libEGL.dll located in `C:\qt\5.3\msvc2013\bin` and `C:Qt\ToolsQtCreator\bin'. I compiled my application by msvc-11.0(2012).

--

I put platforms folder to exe directory and now application runs but crashes immediately in ntdll.dll!771e56bc()

Now my problem is similar to this one [Why is ntdll.dll crashing my c++ executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388350/why-is-ntdll-dll-crashing-my-c-executable).

Can I make debug working like release but save debug mode?

--
Here is Application Verifier result for release mode. It does not happen for debug.

```
=======================================
VERIFIER STOP 00000006: pid 0xDF0: Corrupted heap pointer or using wrong heap. 

    00161000 : Heap handle used in the call.
    093F8FF8 : Heap block involved in the operation.
    00000004 : Size of the heap block.
    06441000 : Heap where block was originally allocated.


=======================================
This verifier stop is not continuable. Process will be terminated 
when you use the `go' debugger command.

=======================================

MyApp.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

AVRF: Noncontinuable verifier stop 00000006 encountered. Terminating process ... 
The thread 0x1724 has exited with code -1073740767 (0xc0000421).
The program '[3568] MyApp.exe' has exited with code -1073740767 (0xc0000421).
```

--

Here is a top of a call stack

```
vrfcore.dll!6ae43466()  Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for vrfcore.dll]   
[External Code] 
qwindows.dll!0f0642cb() Unknown
qwindows.dll!0f065f8a() Unknown
qwindows.dll!0f0662bb() Unknown
Qt5Gui.dll!0f774cf3()   Unknown
Qt5Gui.dll!0f774e75()   Unknown
Qt5Gui.dll!0f7778d5()   Unknown
```

Comment: Are you sure your release build links against the release runtime of Visual Studio? Sounds a bit like mixed debug/release configurations of the involved DLLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But libEGL.dll located in `C:\qt\5.3\msvc2013\bin` and `C:Qt\ToolsQtCreator\bin'

You **must not** take any DLLs from `C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\` -- these are private DLLs for Qt Creator, and they are incompatible with your application.

Only take DLLs from `C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013\bin` and `C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013\plugins`. Here is the required folder structure:

[image: Qt 5 deployment]
*(source: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows )*

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like either a DLL is missing or the application expects it in a different path.

a) Use the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on your release build executable to check whether all DLL dependencies can be resolved.

b) Make sure that your platform plugin files are at the right location. I think they need to be in a folder called "platforms" (not absolutely sure though).

c) There is a [post in the Qt](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/37265) forum about a similar problem. Maybe this helps you to track it down.

Comment: a) Error open file. The system cannot find the file specified: API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL, API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL, API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL, API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL, API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL, API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-1.DLL, DCOMP.DLL, IESHIMS.DLL.

Comment: c) It did not help me.

Comment: Dependeny might give warnings about delay-loaded files which you can ignore. Check for the Qt relevan DLLs (e.g. the platform ones). Does any of these ones show an error?

Comment: Do you talk about this [http://pastebin.com/Vn7mXLuN](http://pastebin.com/Vn7mXLuN)?

Comment: No, these are just missing PDB files, which is not critical for the application start. Btw: if my answer helped to track down the initial (which seems to be the case) it would be nice if you could upvote it.